# Spring data per request repository on in memory database

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, temp-tables, embedded-database

I'm writing a RESTful web service using spring boot. For some computations could be useful load input data into a table of an in memory database (e.g. Hsqldb) and do some aggregations and calculus. But the created table must have a request scope, created and populated on every request.

Is there a way to achieve this pattern using Spring Data or Spring jpa?

I've tried to use @RequestScope annotation on repository interface. I wrote multiple Junit test classes to verify if entities are added on the same table.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create, populate, calculate & drop a table that is named uniquely per request by appending a UUID. I don't think JPA will allow dynamic table names but JDBC can be used.

I suspect that your problem is better solved with [stream aggregations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/index.html#:%7E:text=They%20process%20elements%20from%20a,parameters%20for%20most%20aggregate%20operations.).